# React scale bug

Tags: html, reactjs, web, scale, display

**Hello,**

I created new React App a few days ago and I have a problem.

All elements are bigger, than on the design although it is the same size (1920x1080). And that's because my default system scale is 125%. When I have changed it into 100%, it worked fine. But I want my app to be well displayed on all my users devices (even if they have scale 125% as system default).

**In my index.html I have this line:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Do you know what's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you change scale it updates logical resolution of system. setting it from 100% to 125% it reduces screen width for media query.
Try to handle ot using CSS media query.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought, that there is way to handle it using some tag in html <head>.

Answer (score 1):

As Codesigner mentioned, changing the scale via the web browser changes the width and height of the window (i.e. `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`). The browser then renders the webpage onto the window and scales it to match the dimensions of the viewport.

From the viewpoint of your website, this is equivalent to a change in the size of the browser's window which means you should handle it with CSS media queries.
**But keep in mind** that users making use of the browser's zoom functionality are likely to have a reason to do so (e.g. bad eyesight) meaning you shouldn't scale down your website when a user actually wants to scale it up.

In addition, it is not possible to detect whether a user uses the zoom functionality or actually uses a device with a different physical screen resolution. You might break the responsiveness of your website.